# Changing generated image directory in make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I have used make4ht build system to convert my .tex file to HTML. During the conversion many svg files are generated .Those files lies in the same directory as that of HTML file. Is there any way to move the generated file into a sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can set a base directory for images using the `imgdir` option. It can be used like this:

```
make4ht filename.tex "imgdir:img/"
```

It will not copy the images though, it just puts the directory to image path in the HTML file. You can move images, or output them, to the correct directory using `make4ht` build file, like this:

```lua
local imgdir = "img/"

settings_add {
  tex4ht_sty_par =",imgdir:" .. imgdir
}

Make:image("svg$","dvisvgm --exact -c 1.4,1.4 -n -o " .. imgdir .. "${output} -p ${page} ${source}")
```

The output directory is set in the `imgdir` variable. It is then used in `settings_add` function is used to pass the `imgdir` option, so you don't need to pass it on the command line. `Make:image` function declares command that should be used for creation of the SVG images. You can pass the `imgdir`  variable here too. You need to create the image directory before running this build file!

Use it as:

```
make4ht -e build.lua filename.tex
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello image

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{Intersection point};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

It produces a resulting HTML:

```html
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>Hello image
</p><!-- l. 6 --><p class='indent'>   <img alt='Intersection point
' src='img/sample0x.svg' />
</p>
```

[image]